# EventID 4098 : Group Policy Power Options gets Access Denied when applying a power scheme

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, electrical-power

I created a Group Policy Preference on my Server 2008 R2 DC to Update the Always On power scheme and make that the Active Scheme.

I see the GPO apply in GPResult but the power settings do not change. I get the below event ID in the Application Log on the workstation it is applied to.

```
Event Type: Warning
Event Source:   Group Policy Power Options
Event Category: (2)
Event ID:   4098
Date:       5/12/2011
Time:       1:55:03 PM
User:       NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
Computer:   ARMANI
Description:
The computer 'Always ON' preference item in the 'PowerSetings {4D15031B-44DE-4F68-A123-
EFA07CEEA36B}' Group Policy object did not apply because it failed with error code 
'0x80070005 Access is denied.' This error was suppressed.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```